# C++ - extern int (double)

Tags: c++, mingw, math.h

I'm receiving an error trying to build a program due to file `mingw/include/math.h`

The error states `include/math.h:379:20: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant`

The error is from the following lines

```
extern int __cdecl __isnan (double);
extern int __cdecl __isnanf (float);
extern int __cdecl __isnanl (long double);
```

I'm wondering if I am able to modify these lines to work with my compiler or not, such as making them do the same thing in a compatible way, or what I need to do to fix these errors.

Just as importantly, I am also curious what these lines do.

If it is of any help, I am trying to do `mingw32-make install` freealut after configuring using cmake.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure these headers are intended for that compiler?

Comment: No I am not sure. I am following the article at https://wiki.haskell.org/ALUT, and I have made sure to do everything step-by-step. It doesn't state anything else on the topic.

Comment: Those are part of a standard library header. Don't mess with them. If your program will not compile but millions upon millions of other programs using the same header will, odds are very good the problem is at your end somewhere. That or your compiler installation got mangled somehow and should be repaired or reinstalled. Start by producing a [mcve]. If that doesn't help you spot and fix the error, edit your question to include the MVCE.

Comment: I agree it's on my end somewhere. I'm guessing it might have something to do with compiling under CXX.

Answer (score 2):

The lines each declare a function returning int, one takes double,one float and one long double. The

__cdecl is normally a calling convention indicator but I would check that it has not been #define'd to something else, other than that there is no numeric constant in that code.

Comment: So the lines simply state that it takes a value (double, float, long double) and returns an int? I thought it would be more complex than that. Thank you.